# No funciona el formulario al hacer clic

Tags: angularjs, formularios

Estoy *intentando* hacer un formulario con [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) 1.5 para obtener el token de un servidor, pero al hacer clic no obtengo ningún resultado o mensaje de error.

Uso  **AngularUI Router** para establecer la ruta del formulario...

```
      // otras rutas
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '/app/auth/_login.form.html',
        controler: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs:'in'
      });
      // otras rutas
```

Y puedo visualizar mi formulario correctamente:

```
<!-- Archivo: /app/auth/_login.form.html -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-6">
    <h2>Formulario de Ingreso</h2>
    <form role="form" name="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Nombre de Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="in.credentials.username" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" required />
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" data-ng-model="in.credentials.password" name="password" class="form-control"  id="password" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <button data-ng-submit="in.login(in.credentials)" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

En el botón de enviar establezco que al hacer clic se llame a la función `in.login()` con `credentials` como parámetro. Este es el controlador.

```
(function(angular){
  'use strict';

  function LoginController($scope, $rootScope, auth, session){
    var self = this;
    var _credentials = $scope.credentials;

    var _login = function(_credentials){
      // console.log(_credentials);
      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Esta línea **nunca se ejecuta**
      auth
        .logIn(_credentials)
        .then(function(){
          _user = session.getUser();
        });
    };

    self.login = _login;
    self.credentials = _credentials;
  }

  LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'auth', 'session'];

  angular.module('cmi')
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

})(angular);
```

Las dependencias `auth` y `session` son servicios que solicitan el Token y lo guardan en `LocalStorage` y, *según yo*, ya está verificado su funcionamiento.

### Problema

Al hacer clic en el botón de Ingresar no pasa nada. No hay mensajes de error en la consola y la línea de depuración que coloqué dentro de `_login()` nunca se ejecuta.

Me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal y como corregir mi error.

El resultado esperado es el siguiente: Escribo el nombre de usuario y la contraseña y oprimo el botón enviar. Estos dos datos se pasan al servicio `auth` que los manda al servidor que devuelve un token. Pero no logro pasar del primer paso.

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema está en la directiva que ejecuta el código

```
<button data-ng-submit="in.login(in.credentials)" type="submit" .....
```

La directiva [`ng-submit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) lo que hace es

> Permite ejecutar expresiones de angular a eventos `onsubmit`

Si vas a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/submit)

> Nota que `submit` solo es desencadenado en elementos `form`, no en el botón o input tipo `submit`. (Los formularios son enviados, no los botones.)

Esta directiva debería estar en tu `form`

```
<form role="form" name="form" data-ng-submit="in.login(in.credentials)">
```

no en el botón como lo tienes ahora. Puedes ponerla en el botón si la cambias por `ng-click`.

Las [reglas](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) para hacer submit a los formularios de angular son las siguientes

- directiva `ng-submit` en el elemento `form`
- directiva `ng-click` en el primer botón o `input` tipo `submit`

Para evitar doble ejecución del evento usa o `ng-click` o `ng-submit` pero no ambos.

Por cierto no necesitas escribir

```
`in.login(in.credentials)`
```

ya que `vm.credentials` o `in.credentials` está disponible en tu controller así que puedes escibir

```
`in.login()`
```

y utilizar los valores en el código directamente.